# How do I find number of subsets satisfying two constraints?

Tags: set, subset, set-theory

Suppose I have a set: `A = {1, 2, 3, 4}`.

I have to find the number of subsets of size `K`, which must have an element `p`.

---

For example `K = 3`, `p = 2` - then the subsets must be of size `3` and must have an element `2`.

In this case, the number of such subsets is `3`.

#### How can I calculate it using formulas?

Answer (score 0):

- Each subset must have `K - 1` elements other than `p`.
- The amount of such elements is `len(A) - 1`.

So your answer is `(len(A) - 1) choose (K - 1)`.

---

It is equal to `(len(A) - 1)! / [ (K - 1)! * (len(A) - K)! ]`

---

For your example:

```
(4 - 1)! / [ (3 - 1)! * (4 - 3)! ] = 
6 / [ 2 * 1 ] = 3
```